# hibernate 4.x with second level Ehcache not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ehcache

Here's my config:

pom.xml:
Using hibernate and hibernate-ehcache 4.2.8.Final version

spring config: i have the following hibernate properties

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
```

ehcache.xml

```
<ehcache>

    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>

    <!--  cache setting for com.cisco.locker.entity.SystemConfig entity -->
    <cache name="com.cisco.locker.entity.SystemConfig"
        maxElementsInMemory="100"
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="600"
        timeToLiveSeconds="600"
        overflowToDisk="false"
        statistics="true"
        />

</ehcache>
```

entity  - com.cisco.locker.entity.SystemConfig.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "system_config")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class SystemConfig implements Serializable {
...
}
```

logs:

```
First call: http://localhost:8080/test/getSystemConfigs
{
    "statusCode": "200",
    "statusMessage": "SUCCESS",
    "response": {
        "admin.lcu_status_polling_timer": "120",
        "admin.site_status_polling_interval": "15"
    }
}

Hibernate: select systemconf0_.ID as ID1_12_, systemconf0_.description as descript2_12_, systemconf0_.property as property3_12_, systemconf0_.value as value4_12_ from system_config systemconf0_ where systemconf0_.property like ?
2014-05-13 00:53:40,553 DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.Cache [http-bio-8080-exec-1]: com.cisco.locker.entity.SystemConfig cache - Miss
2014-05-13 00:53:40,561 DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.Cache [http-bio-8080-exec-1]: com.cisco.locker.entity.SystemConfig cache - Miss

Second call: http://localhost:8080/test/getSystemConfigs
{
    "statusCode": "200",
    "statusMessage": "SUCCESS",
    "response": {
        "admin.lcu_status_polling_timer": "120",
        "admin.site_status_polling_interval": "15"
    }
}

Hibernate: select systemconf0_.ID as ID1_12_, systemconf0_.description as descript2_12_, systemconf0_.property as property3_12_, systemconf0_.value as value4_12_ from system_config systemconf0_ where systemconf0_.property like ?
2014-05-13 00:53:48,037 DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.Cache [http-bio-8080-exec-2]: com.cisco.locker.entity.SystemConfigCache: com.cisco.locker.entity.SystemConfig store hit for com.cisco.locker.entity.SystemConfig#11
2014-05-13 00:53:48,037 DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.Cache [http-bio-8080-exec-2]: com.cisco.locker.entity.SystemConfigCache: com.cisco.locker.entity.SystemConfig store hit for com.cisco.locker.entity.SystemConfig#12


Third call – After manually changing value in DB "admin.site_status_polling_interval" from 15 to 10: http://localhost:8080/test/getSystemConfigs
{
    "statusCode": "200",
    "statusMessage": "SUCCESS",
    "response": {
        "admin.lcu_status_polling_timer": "120",
        "admin.site_status_polling_interval": "10"
    }
}

Hibernate: select systemconf0_.ID as ID1_12_, systemconf0_.description as descript2_12_, systemconf0_.property as property3_12_, systemconf0_.value as value4_12_ from system_config systemconf0_ where systemconf0_.property like ?
2014-05-13 00:54:08,738 DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.Cache [http-bio-8080-exec-4]: com.cisco.locker.entity.SystemConfigCache: com.cisco.locker.entity.SystemConfig store hit for com.cisco.locker.entity.SystemConfig#11
2014-05-13 00:54:08,738 DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.Cache [http-bio-8080-exec-4]: com.cisco.locker.entity.SystemConfigCache: com.cisco.locker.entity.SystemConfig store hit for com.cisco.locker.entity.SystemConfig#12
```

I dont seem to understand how the cache picked up the latest values when i ended up doing a manual DB change. The logs suggest it is picking these changed values also from the cache.

Does the second level cache pick up manual DB changes i.e. DB changes not going through hibernate as the above logs suggest? or is there something wrong that i am doing?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as the log suggests, a SQL query is executed against the database. The data comes from the database, not from the cache. The hits you see are store hits.

To get entities from the cache, use `session.get()`, not queries.

Comment: JB Nizet... the api is using session.get() internally. You are seeing the SQL query in the log since i have hibernate.show_sql=true property set. Also what exactly do you mean by "The hits you see are store hits" Doesnt it mean it is getting the values from cache? appreciate your help!

Comment: All your where clauses are `where systemconf0_.property like ?`. That can't be the result of `session.get()`. And to me, a store hit is when somethign is being *stored* in the cache. Not *got* from the cache.

Comment: you are right i'm using HQL queries not session.get(). let me try using session.get().